# Jenkins: Suppress builds after commit by a system user possible?

Tags: jenkins, svn

have a localiziation build in Jenkins (sources are in SVN) that has a commit by the build user as last build step - due to shortcomings of the used localization tool (Passolo).

Is there a way to suppress the triggering of a new build when the commit was done by this special build user or to kill those jobs immediately?

TIA, Franz-Josef

Answer (score 0):

The solution ist to use the "revprop" attribute in your build script, like so:

`svn commit -m "Commit via Jenkins" --with-revprop NoAutoBuild`

Inside Jenkins configuration, you can exclude revisions using this property from starting a new build, you find the option in the SVN section of the Jenkins configuration page (screenshot, alas, in German):

[sreenshot showing the "exlude revprop" section of the SVN plug-in inside Jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMB4U.png)

Hope this helps you (and me, if I forget until next time :-)